# Can DNA rings, i.e. plasmids, form as Möbius strips?

Tags: molecular-biology, dna, microbiology, topology

I know that plasmids can be present in a coiled form, which keeps the DNA strands together when they degenerate, by forming catenases.

I was wondering, however, whether it has been documented to naturally happen or if anybody has ever successfully created a Möbius-strip plasmid. Technically, such a structure could readily form from a single circular strand of DNA, but the literature, as far as I have searched, has remained silent.

Comment: Wouldn’t any covalently closer circular DNA with an odd twist be a Mobius strip?

Comment: Related to your question, [this paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/nnano.2010.193) reports Möbius strips created from multiple strands of DNA.

Comment: @canadianer you can make this into an answer, since it answers my question.